# Socket accept failed using Http11Nio2Protocol - Tomcat9.0.35

Tags: tomcat, protocols

I'm getting the error below while using the protocol "org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol".
Does anyone knows why this happens and how to fix it?

Tomcat version : 9.0.35

```
24-Mar-2021 08:07:23.987 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio2-443"]
24-Mar-2021 08:07:23.987 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [11,250] milliseconds
24-Mar-2021 08:07:24.006 SEVERE [https-jsse-nio2-443-exec-2] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Nio2Endpoint$Nio2Acceptor.failed Socket accept failed
    java.io.IOException: The specified network name is no longer available
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Iocp.translateErrorToIOException(Iocp.java:299)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Iocp$EventHandlerTask.run(Iocp.java:389)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

Comment: The NIC the socket is bound to has gone down. BInd to 0.0.0.0.

Comment: @Daniel Seleme Did you find the root cause of this? Please add as an answer if you had found.